# in app purchase not using storekit

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, storekit

I want to make an application that make the users able to order food through my application and they can pay using their credit card or any other payment method. and I don't want apple to take 30% of the transaction.

what methods are available to do this, and is this illegal for Apple?

Thanks

Comment: You can't do that. You're required to use the in-app purchase system. Additionally, you can't buy real world goods with this system. I'd do what Matt S. suggests.

Comment: Amazon sells me real physical goods through their native iOS app *all the time*. There's nothing wrong with this.

Comment: @Jack, from where I'm standing, you're half right: you're required to use IAP _for content/services purchases_, and not allowed to use it to purchase physical goods. However, the combination of these requirements does not restrict ordering/paying for physical goods via a non-IAP system.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Apple kind of has this whole thing locked down though. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use storekit to do this, Apple will reject it immediately (violates 11.3 in the agreement).  If you REALLY want to do that, you have two options:

1.) Write a web app instead of a native iOS app.

2.) Do something like what [Square](https://squareup.com/) is doing where they process credit card payments through their own service.

Comment: can I add the webview inside my native app to do payments, and my app wont be rejected

Comment: Absolutely not. If it's a native app it's under apple's rules. That's similar to the "stunt" amazon pulled that caused apple to change the rules.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://techcrunch.com/2011/06/09/apple-switches-up-in-app-purchase-policy-for-publishers/) leads me to believe that if you're not purchasing *content* or additional *application features*, any purchases the user makes are not subject to royalties collectable by Apple.

That said, you'll have to find some service (presumably a web service, like [Amazon FPS](http://aws.amazon.com/fps/)) that will process the food payments in a way that works for your business process.